# Click before a specific word within <p> tag using Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, xpath

We are using Selenium Webdriver for Test automation. Here is my requirement.

HTML looks like this.

```
<p> I need to click before this. Help me achieve this </p>
```

The text within "p" tag can have any number of lines. I get a specific word as test input and need to place cursor before that word.

I tried locating element using Xpath contains text, it returns the entire paragraph and clicks in the middle of the paragraph(for chrome).

Can some one help me how I can achieve this ?

Comment: share more HTML code

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can specify coordinates using [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

In C# and Java you can use [Actions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By...);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(dx, dy).click().perform();
```

Comment: Guy, to find the x,y coordinates of the text inside the <p> tag is the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Use getSize function and then divide height and width of element, after that apply Action class click method, here is sample code:

```
   WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath"));
    Dimension location = el.getSize();
    int y = location.height/2;
    int x = location.width/2;
    Actions build = new Actions(driver);
    build.moveToElement(el, x, y).click().build().perform();
```

Hope this will work!!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't have an API to directly deal with a text node.
However you can retrieve the word position with a piece of JavaScript and click the previous word with the Actions class by providing an offset position relative to the element holding the text.

This is an example that double clicks the word in front of "Exchange" which is "Stack":

```
// script to get the relative position/size of a word in an element
final String JS_GET_WORD_RECT =
    "var ele=arguments[0], word=arguments[1], rg=document.createRange();   " +
    "for(var c=ele.firstChild, i; c; c=c.nextSibling){                     " +
    "  if(c.nodeType != 3 || (i=c.nodeValue.indexOf(word)) < 0) continue;  " +
    "  rg.setStart(c, i); rg.setEnd(c, i + word.length);                   " +
    "  var r = ele.getBoundingClientRect(), rr = rg.getClientRects()[0];   " +
    "  return { left: (rr.left-r.left) | 0, top: (rr.top-r.top) | 0,       " +
    "           width: rr.width | 0, height: rr.height | 0 };              " +
    "};";


WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// load the page
driver.get("http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy");

// get the text element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sectionheader > h2:nth-child(1)"));

// get the relative position/size {left, top, width, height} for the word "Exchange"
Map rect = (Map)js.executeScript(JS_GET_WORD_RECT, element, "Exchange");

// define a relative ckick point for the previous word "Stack"
Long offset_x = (long)rect.get("left") - (long)rect.get("width") / 2;
Long offset_y = (long)rect.get("top") + (long)rect.get("height") / 2;

// double click the word "Stack"
new Actions(driver)
    .moveToElement(element, offset_x.intValue(), offset_y.intValue())
    .doubleClick()
    .perform();

driver.quit();
```